# Magento 2 : How to update the minicart according to the stock status when the user logged in?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.4

Scenario -
Here the user logged in and added some products to the basket then he logged out. After sometime he logged in to purchase the products,but some of those products are not available.

Now when he click on the minicart, I need to remove the out of stock items from the minicart and show an error message like :

> xxx,yyy products are removed due to out of stock

And show the available products as it is.

How can i achive this?
Thanks.

Comment: before loading mini cart check the stock status using plugin and save the sku id in cookie as out of stock product and use remove function of quote item. and while load mini cart display that product as out of stock as u want to display. If you want to learn magento2 Join my Blog https://www.createswowtech.com

Comment: sir, can you explain in detail